# SwitchButton (in custom view) value is not checked after rotation

Tags: android, rotation, switch-statement

I need to create custom view - `TextView` and `Switch` button.

I have custom view:

```
public class CustomTextWithSwitch extends LinearLayout implements View.OnClickListener {

  private CustomTextWithSwitchBinding binding;
  private boolean defaultValue;

  public CustomTextWithSwitch(Context context) {
      this(context, null);
  }

  public CustomTextWithSwitch(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
      this(context, attrs, 0);
  }

  public CustomTextWithSwitch(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
      binding = CustomTextWithSwitchBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()), this);
      TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTextWithSwitch);
      defaultValue = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CustomTextWithSwitch_defaultValue, false);
      a.recycle();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onFinishInflate() {
      ...
      binding.sToggle.setChecked(defaultValue);
      super.setOnClickListener(this);

      super.onFinishInflate();
  }

  public void toggle() {
      binding.sToggle.toggle();
      defaultValue = binding.sToggle.isChecked();
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
      toggle();
  }

  public void setDefaultValue(boolean defaultValue) {
      this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
      binding.sToggle.setChecked(defaultValue);
    }
}
```

I use that in the activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      ...
      myCustomView.setDefaultValue(true);
  }
}
```

When I open this activity, everything works as expected - switch button is checked. However, when I rotate the screen, it is **checked to false**. Can somebody advise what am I doing incorrectly? Note: I use `ViewModel` and the value is restored correctly. However, the `Switch` button in this custom view is not toggled.

**UPDATE:** This issue happens only when I have another `CustomTextWithSwich` in my activity, so it means they have effect on each other(it seems that default value is set according to second `View`). Is it possible to separate them, so they are standalone?

Comment: How does your `CustomTextWithSwitchBinding` class looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a [ViewModdel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel). During rotation it is normal that you will lost the states. `ViewModel` will not be destroyed during app rotation so the last state of `CustomTextWithSwich` will be not lost.

On the other hand you can override `onConfigurationChanged` method every time app is rotated this method will run, so you can use it to set your data.

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

Comment: I am using `ViewModel`. The value is restored on configuration change, but `Switch` button is not toggled.

Comment: @Tom11 Did you try to set status of `Switch` in `onConfigurationChanged` method  reading from `ViewModel` ?

Comment: Yes, still the same issue.

Comment: @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        myCustomView.setDefaultValue(viewModel.isSwitchChecked);
}
//
You need too use like this

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether both of your `CustomTextWithSwitch` and its children on Activity has `android:id`s. Ids should be different. In this case Android take care about saving instance state for your view.

If it does not save your state, use this code inside your `CustomTextWithSwitch`

```
@Override
  public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState()
  {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("superState", super.onSaveInstanceState());
    bundle.putBoolean("isChecked", defaultValue); // ... save check state 
    return bundle;
  }

  @Override
  public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state)
  {
    if (state instanceof Bundle)
    {
      Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
      defaultValue = bundle.getBoolean("isChecked"); // ... load state
      binding.sToggle.setChecked(defaultValue);
      state = bundle.getParcelable("superState");
    }
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
  }
```

Comment: I use IDs. The problem is, that it saves instance state, but do not toggle `Switch` button.

Answer (score 0):

Have faced the same issue. I fixed it by setting [setSaveEnabled(false)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setSaveEnabled(boolean)) on the switch view. Just let the viewModel restore it's state.

```
public CustomTextWithSwitch(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
      binding = CustomTextWithSwitchBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()), this);
      TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTextWithSwitch);
      defaultValue = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CustomTextWithSwitch_defaultValue, false);
      a.recycle();

    //Add this (assuming your switch view id is 'switch_view')
    binding.switchView.setSaveEnabled(false);
}
```